# Eclipse android preferencesfile; cant read the values of the keys

Tags: android, eclipse, sharedpreferences

I'm pretty new at programming for Android and I want to excuse myself for any mistakes that I did, because I'm German :)

I'm programming an app for my school.
In this app I have tried to make an editable timetable, so that everybody can write his personal timetable. I did that by creating a `SharedPreferences` file, but when I edit the values and look if they have changed, the values are just the "default values" and not the values I typed in at the `EditText` elements.

Here is my code :

#### Edit Activity

```
@SuppressLint("CommitPrefEdits")
public class MondayEditActivity extends Activity {
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPreferencesFile";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mondayedit);

    final EditText stunde1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.getStunde1); 
    //Stunde is german for hour
    final EditText stunde2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.getStunde2);
    // get Stunde = Edit Text element
    final EditText stunde3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.getStunde3);
    final EditText stunde4 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.getStunde4);
    final EditText stunde5 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.getStunde5);
    final EditText stunde6 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.getStunde6);
    final EditText stunde7 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.getStunde7);
    final EditText stunde8 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.getStunde8);
    final EditText stunde9 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.getStunde9);
    final EditText stunde10 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.getStunde10);
    Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bestaetigen);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
            editor.putString("stunde1", stunde1.getText().toString());
            editor.putString("stunde2", stunde2.getText().toString());
            editor.putString("stunde3", stunde3.getText().toString());
            editor.putString("stunde4", stunde4.getText().toString());
            editor.putString("stunde5", stunde5.getText().toString());
            editor.putString("stunde6", stunde6.getText().toString());
            editor.putString("stunde7", stunde7.getText().toString());
            editor.putString("stunde8", stunde8.getText().toString());
            editor.putString("stunde9", stunde9.getText().toString());
            editor.putString("stunde10", stunde10.getText().toString());

            startActivity(new Intent(MondayEditActivity.this, MondayActivity.class));

        }
    });
   }

     @Override
     public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.monday_edit, menu);
        return true;
     }

}
```

This is the Activity where it should be, but there is only the "default value"...

```
public class MondayActivity extends Activity {

    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPreferencesFile";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_monday);
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);

        TextView tvStunde1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textviewstunde1);
        TextView tvStunde2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textviewstunde2);
        TextView tvStunde3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textviewstunde3);
        TextView tvStunde4 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textviewstunde4);
        TextView tvStunde5 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textviewstunde5);
        TextView tvStunde6 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textviewstunde6);
        TextView tvStunde7 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textviewstunde7);
        TextView tvStunde8 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textviewstunde8);
        TextView tvStunde9 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textviewstunde9);
        TextView tvStunde10 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textviewstunde10);

        tvStunde1.setText(settings.getString("stunde1", "-"));
        tvStunde2.setText(settings.getString("stunde2", "-"));
        tvStunde3.setText(settings.getString("stunde3", "-"));
        tvStunde4.setText(settings.getString("stunde4", "-"));
        tvStunde5.setText(settings.getString("stunde5", "-"));
        tvStunde6.setText(settings.getString("stunde6", "-"));
        tvStunde7.setText(settings.getString("stunde7", "-"));
        tvStunde8.setText(settings.getString("stunde8", "-"));
        tvStunde9.setText(settings.getString("stunde9", "-"));
        tvStunde10.setText(settings.getString("stunde10", "-"));



    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.monday, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

I hope you can understand my problem and help me, I really don't know what to do and I'm trying to solve the problem for 3 hours.

Comment: After editing/storing the preferences you need to call _editor.commit()_ to actually save them.

Comment: Oh ... that simple? I hoped it would be a more complex mistake. But it helped ! Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the following line to your `onClick` method:

```
editor.commit();
```

or alternatively, if you're only supporting API-Level 11 and above

```
editor.apply();
```

Just to clear things app: Your changes weren't saved previously. You have to call `apply()` or `commit()` explicity to save the changes.
Right from the [Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#apply%28%29):

> Commit your preferences changes back from this Editor to the
>   SharedPreferences object it is editing. This atomically performs the
>   requested modifications, replacing whatever is currently in the
>   SharedPreferences.